# Binary Index tree in java

Tags: java, dictionary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, b-tree

I'm learning how to implement a binary index tree. How should I go about building a Binary tree with a set of Strings as my input? I believe there are two data structures 1) regular Binary tree - where we do inorder postorder 2) Binary index tree

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] docs = {"The idea is that all are strings",
                     "position of the node is considered",
                     "Being positive helps",
                     "I want to learn then add and search in the tree"
                    };
}
```

Bstnode

```
 public class BSTNode
{
private String key;
private Object value;
private BSTNode left, right;

public BSTNode( String key, Object value )
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

//if key not found in BST then it is added. If jey already exists then that node's value
//is updated.
public void put( String key, Object value )
{
    if ( key.compareTo( this.key ) < 0 )         
    {             
        if ( left != null )             
        {                 
            left.put( key, value );             
        }             
        else             
        {                 
            left = new BSTNode( key, value );             
        }         
    }         
    else if ( key.compareTo( this.key ) > 0 )
    {
        if ( right != null )
        {
            right.put( key, value );
        }
        else
        {
            right = new BSTNode( key, value );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //update this one
        this.value = value;
    }
}

//find Node with given key and return it's value
public Object get( String key )
{
    if ( this.key.equals( key ) )
    {
        return value;
    }

    if ( key.compareTo( this.key ) < 0 )
    {
        return left == null ? null : left.get( key );
    }
    else
    {
        return right == null ? null : right.get( key );
    }
}
```

}

Please let me know a good tutorial or a start to go about building a binary indexed tree.

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWDQJGaN1gY

Comment: Note: [binary index trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or BIT (also known as Fenwick trees) have little or nothing to do with binary search trees (a.k.a. BST); they are used for purposes like efficiently querying a running total at a given point/node, or a sum over a given range. As such these beasts are completely different from binary search trees. IOW, a binary search tree is not a *binary index tree* even if it is used as some kind of index.

Answer (score 1):

`Trees` and `Lists` should be generic in Java.  There's no sense restricting yourself to `Strings`.

Any good book on data structures will give you a good start.

I've done this in Java.  You are welcome to the source:

https://github.com/duffymo